# Read variables from database value

Tags: php, mysql, variables

When I store a variable in the database, and for variable I mean the name of the variable, for example, I store in the database:

```
lorem ipsum dolor $var amet
```

or

```
lorem ipsum dolor {$var} amet
```

When I try to get the value with PHP from the database, the variable is not executed, so when I try to print the value it show me:

```
lorem ipsum dolor $var amet
```

I need that PHP doesn't interpret the var as string, but it show me the content of the variable. For example, if `$var = "sit"`, when I get the value from the database, it show me:

```
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

I can't store the value of the variable directly in the database because it's a dynamic variable. It's a lang variable, that changes according to the language chosen from the user. So I need something that when I get the value from the database, it check if there's any var inside and if there's a var change it with its value.

Comment: no, this isn't a thing - any issue with storing separate rows for unique strings that you can call via an id?

Comment: You need a function __curly_replacer()__ and then put the values in an array. Use a format like ```lorem ipsum dolor {var_name} amet```. The function would then take two args, the template and the array. The function simple does a str_replace for '{'.array(i).'}' with the values. I'll post it as an answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example script to show how to use the curly_replacer function:

```
<?php

//  Load array with values:
$lang_str = array(
    'name' => 'namo',
    'another' => 'something else',
    'something' => 'another string'
);

//  Create a template
$tmpl = 'lorem ipsum {name} dolor {another} ipsum {something}';

echo "<p>Template: " . $tmpl . "</p>\n";
echo "<p>Results: " . curly_replacer($tmpl,$lang_str);

function curly_replacer($content = '', $data = array(), $exploder = '.', $replace_null = false){
    preg_match_all('/{([^(}|{| )]*?)}/i', $content, $curly_matches);
    if(isset($curly_matches[1]) && !empty($curly_matches[1])){
        foreach($curly_matches[1] as $match){
            $value = $this->get_array_value($data, explode($exploder, $match));
            if(!is_null($value)){
                if(is_array($value)){
                    $content = str_replace("{".$match."}", var_export($value, true), $content);
                }else{
                    $content = str_replace("{".$match."}", $value, $content);
                }
            }else{
                if($replace_null === true){
                    $content = str_replace("{".$match."}", '', $content);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
?>
```

Create an array of name/value pairs that may appear in the templates.

In the template, use the form `{var_name}` where you want the values substituted.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Actually I tried it but it gives me a fatal error: `Using $this when not in object context`

Answer (score 0):

To simplify @Timur's answer: 
Save `lorem ipsum dolor %s amet` to your database. Then when you retrieve it, use the following:

```
$stringFromDB = **code to get string from db**;
$modifiedString = sprintf($stringFromDB, $var);
```

`$modifiedString` should now be `lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` as per your example.

Answer (score -1):

Use instead of $var in string use function [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).
You can write your code like that:

```
sprintf('lorem ipsum dolor %s amet' $var);
```